# Loading only two products on category page Magento

Tags: magento, pagination, categories, product

I am working on the site where after showing the pagination i got two products on each category.I am trying to show 12 or above products but didn't get that.I have tried this code but not worked.

```
<action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>12</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>12</limit></action>
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this link. This might serve your purpose:

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41005/product-count-per-category-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

In default magento provides the feature that allows the customer to show number of product per page. Have you checked Under

> system->Configuration->Catalog tab

The field highlighted in the screenshot is responsible to display the number of product per page.

[image]

If it is alright than there may be some product count check in your template file.
Check the file below.

> design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Is there any condition for checking the number of product per page.

Hope this may help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml as the previous poster suggested and output the product count coming out:

Before line 38:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    var_dump( $_productCollection->count() );
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
```

If it shows 2 it means you may need to do a category_flat_reindex:

go to terminal and navigate to `root/shell`

Run `php indexer.php info`

Run `php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat`

Please post the package/theme you're using if that doesn't work.